# Syntax error near "from" in amazon redshift query

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am working on queries in Amazon RedShift.

I have created in query in which I am getting syntax error but I am unable to know the issue behind it. The query looks OK to me.

Below is the query:

```
select (TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE 'epoch' + (_action_date::float / 1000000) * INTERVAL '1 second') as eta
where eta >= (SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY')
from trips;
```

Here, _action_date is a bigint integer so I am converting it into timestamp format also.
I am trying to extract those rows in which _action_date  is greater than or equal to yesterday date.

The error I am getting:

> Error running query: syntax error at or near "from" LINE 1: ...ta where eta >= (SELECT NOW() - INTERVAL '1 DAY') from trips... ^

Please help me in correcting it. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The `from` clause goes after `select` and before `where`.  I consider this a simple typo.

Comment: I am getting this error now: Error running query: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.

Comment: Unrelated, but: there is no need to prefix `now()` with a select. You can use a scalar function in an expression without the need of a SELECT.

Comment: You should be using `datediff` function like https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html

Answer (score 0):

```
select (TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE 'epoch' + (_action_date::float / 1000000) * 
INTERVAL '1 second') as eta
from trips
where eta >= (SELECT getdate() - INTERVAL '1 DAY');
```

Comment: Getting this error: Error running query: Specified types or functions (one per INFO message) not supported on Redshift tables.

Comment: This code only answer doesn't really explain how that code is different, or why the changes have been made. Could you expand it to explain what and why?